# Adding a file to the scan exclusion list in Avast Antivirus

Tags: avast

Using Avast Antivirus, is it possible to add a file to the scan exclusion list? I got a popup message saying that a "suspicious file" had been detected, and then I tried clicking "Add this file to the scan exclusion list", and it appeared that nothing happened at all. Is there any other way to exclude a specific file from the scan list?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem myself.  And you are right, I tried to select the link to add the file to exclusion list and it doesn't do anything (meaning, if you click it, the UI doesn't do anything at all; the popup still says there).

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Bring up the Avast User Interface (right click on Avast tray icon and select Open Avast! User Interface)
2. Scan
3. Settings
4. Exclusions
5. Browse to a directory or path and select
6. Add
7. Ok

Comment: Does not work..

Comment: Adding an exclusion under the "DeepScreen" tab seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is some bug in the UI as suggested. The button just doesnt work.

So the solution to fixing it, is:

1. Open avast! user interface.
2. Scan
3. Quarantine (Virus Chest) - Along the bottom.
4. Right click file
5. Restore and Add to Exclusions.

Comment: Does not work..